# Parse numerical value from glossaries variable

Tags: macros, glossaries, calculations, pgfmath

Can I parse the text returned from `\gls*{...}` and get latex to recognize it as a numerical variable so that I can use it in a calculation?  This calculation could be done using `calculator`, `fp`, `calc` or `pgf` depending what I run into concerning package conflicts.  I am compiling in `XeLaTeX` and `TeX4HT`.

The primary reason why I turned to the `glossaries` package to manage was because of the presence of symbols such as `.` `_` `+` `-` etc in the names of the variables.  The presence of these precludes the possibility that they will be suitable names for `newcommands`.  I will likely post another question later trying to figure out if it's possible to import a table from a csv file and iterate through it until the matching string argument is found, and then return the value on the same line in a specific column, within a `newcommand`, but I am hoping it's easier to parse a number from a string returned by a gls call.

In the MWE below the different approaches I have tried are commented out to permit compilation to show the success of the glossaries definition and calculation functions.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}
    \usepackage[nogroupskip,toc,acronym]{glossaries} 
    \usepackage{scrwfile}
    \usepackage{calculator}
    \usepackage{fp}
    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage{pgf}

    \usepackage{siunitx}

    \newglossary[datag]{data}{datat}{datan}{Data}

    \newglossaryentry{d.A_Control-0}{ type={data},  name={1.1}, first={1.1}, description={1.1} }

    \newglossaryentry{d.B_Sample-2}{ type={data},  name={1.08059784043081}, first={1.08059784043081}, description={1.08059784043081} }


    \newcommand{\foldfp}[3]{
        \FPeval{result}{round(#1/#2,#3)}
        \result
    }

    \newcommand{\foldcalculator}[3]{
        \DIVIDE{#1}{#2}{\dsol}  
        \dsol   
        %\DIVIDE{\gls*{#1}}{\gls*{#2}}{\dsol}   
        %\DIVIDE{{#1}}{{#2}}{\dsol} 
        %\ROUND[#3]{\dsol}{\rsol}
        %\rsol
    }

    \begin{document}


        \begin{itemize}
            \item \gls*{d.A_Control-0}
            \item \gls*{d.B_Sample-2}
            \item \glsentryfirst{d.A_Control-0}
            \item \foldfp{33}{2}{2} - proof that the calculation function works fine.
            \item \foldcalculator{33}{2}{2} - proof that the calculation function works fine.
            %\item \num{\gls*{d.A_Control-0}}
            %\item \number{\gls*{d.A_Control-0}}
            %\item \foldfp{\gls*{d.A_Control-0}}{\gls*{d.B_Sample-2}}{2}
            %\item \foldcalculator{\gls*{d.A_Control-0}}{\gls*{d.B_Sample-2}}{2}            
        \end{itemize}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: `\gls*` is `protected`, therefore not expandable, unfortunately. Nice question, anyway

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for your comment.  Are `\glsentryfirst` or any of the other `\glsentryxxx` fields also protected? Might I be able to use one of these macros to define a custom macro that would parse this constant value?  I think I understand the purpose behind protecting `gls` calls because they are dynamic, however the `glsentry` equivalents are constants...  Is there any potential to adapt the question with these calls as shown in `\item` three of the original question?

Comment: Quick check for your first question (in comment): `\glsentryfirst` isn't protected, but I am not really familiar with `glossaries`, so I don't know the various `\glsentryxxx` commands. Try yourself (in a terminal) `texdef -t latex -p glossaries glsentryxxx` (replace glsentryxxx with the real macro name)

Comment: The expandable commands are the non-case-changing `\glsentryxxx` commands listed in [Using Glossary Terms Without Links](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:glsnolink). (It's also possible to use `\glsletentryfield` to assign to contents of a particular field to a command, which you could then use in an expandable context.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Much thanks for your comment, not to mention the `glossaries` package itself.  I have solved my question using `\glsentryname{#n}` instead of `\gls*{#n}` inside the newcommand performing the ratio.  Could have sworn I had tried that in the form of `\glsentryfirst{#n}`.  I am having some trouble visualizing how `\glsletentryfield` would improve this because from what I understand, I still have to assign a custom function name.  In macro form this would be overwritten with each call, but how is that different than using the call to the field using `\glsentryxxx`?

Comment: TeX is not designed for this sort of job and it is not very good at it. There are better ways to process data prior to inclusion in a `.tex` file.... ('better' meaning faster, easier, more elegant, more flexible, more robust....) Why do you want to process data with TeX of all things? It is like trying to grate carrots with a hole punch. You might eventually get something passably somewhat like grated carrot, but you'd get a better result quicker and easier if you used a grater instead.

Comment: I only mentioned `\glsletentryfield` because it was listed immediately after all the `\glsentryxxx` commands in that section. (It can be useful if you're only dealing with one-level expansion rather than full expansion, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.)

Comment: Perhaps, using `calculator`and  defining `\newcommand{\foldcalculator}[3]{\DIVIDE{#1}{#2}{\dsol}      \ROUND[#3]{\dsol}{\rsol}\rsol}` and using `\glsentryname`instead of `\gls*` may work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all who commented, here is my summary of the problem evolution and solution:

1. I was mistaken in interpreting the unexpanded `\gls*{}` entries as a numerical parse problem.  Thanks to @ChristianHupfer
2. I can use `\glsentryname{}` to grab the expanded definition.  Thanks to @NicolaTalbot
3. Now that I am using an expanded variable correctly, there isn't actually a problem recognizing the defined term (a number in excel - rather than use LaTeX to parse and evaluate my content, I use a formula in excel to control the digits/rounding of the raw data stored as gls entry outputs).  Thanks to @cfr.
4. Lastly I couldn't continue to use the calculator package because it uses a modified division algorithm that does not return sufficiently accurate results.  Instead I used the following code.

fold command:

```
\newcommand{\folds}[2]{%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\ifdimgreater{\glsentryname{#1} pt}{\glsentryname{#2} pt}}}%
    {%
        \FPeval{result}{round(\glsentryname{#1}/\glsentryname{#2},\rfndp)}%
        \num{\result}%
    }% true
    {%
        \FPeval{result}{round(\glsentryname{#2}/\glsentryname{#1},\rfndp)}%
        \num{\result}%
    }% false
}
```